# How to get name of column for use in SELECT clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a table in an Access DB that has columns for each of the 12 months of the year. The columns have names of "1" to "12". That is to say, the names of the columns are just the number of the month it represents. The columns contain numbers as data, and I need to sum the columns for the months remaining in the year. For example, right now we're in September, so I'd need the `SELECT` clause to sum the values in columns (months) 9 through 12. This must be able to dynamically sum up the relevant months, so that next month (Oct) Sep will be excluded and only 10 through 12 are summed.

How can I reference the name of the column in the `SELECT` clause to be able to perform a test on it. I need something like the following:

```
IIf(Table1.[1].ColumnName >= Month(Now), Table1.[1], 0) 
+ IIf(Table1.[2].ColumnName >= Month(Now), Table1.[2], 0)
...
+ IIf(Table1.[12].ColumnName >= Month(Now), Table1.[12], 0)
```

This would be one approach, but, in passing, if there's a better way to do this, please let me know as well.

I've seen other posts on SO that discuss returning all column names for a table. That is not what I need here. I need to return the column name and perform tests on it within a `SELECT` clause. Thanks.

EDIT
I understand that this structure (having the data across 12 different columns) is not the greatest. This is not a new DB that I'm setting up. It is an old DB that I've inherited, so I can't make changes to the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understood your question, but it would seem the major issue is the fact that you store values in different columns instead of something like .

One solution could be to use `union` in a subquery to make the columns  available to the outer select and use that to filter, sum and group by.

If you have a table looking like:

```
id (number, primary key), 1..12 (number, month values)
```

Then a query like this should work (this is for month 1-5 only):

```
SELECT id, SUM(MonthValue) AS SumFutureMonths 
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS MonthNo, id, YourTable.[1] AS MonthValue FROM YourTable 
    union all
    SELECT 2 AS MonthNo, id, YourTable.[2] AS MonthValue FROM YourTable 
    union all
    SELECT 3 AS MonthNo, id, YourTable.[3] AS MonthValue FROM YourTable 
    union all
    SELECT 4 AS MonthNo, id, YourTable.[4] AS MonthValue FROM YourTable 
    union all
    SELECT 5 AS MonthNo, id, YourTable.[5] AS MonthValue FROM YourTable 
) 
WHERE MonthNo > MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY id
```

Whether it would perform well I can't say - it depends on your data, but the retrieving all data in the table for a union can be a costly operation. Anyway, please try it out to see if it works.

Comment: This essentially creates a "temp" table in a structure that the data should've been created in the first place to be able to do the `SELECT`s and `JOIN`s I need. Clever. It's not a huge DB, so the performance is still pretty good, and, in any case, the performance is not so important for what I need. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works in Access; but in MS SQL you can write a string and execute it..
For example

```
@sqlStr = "Select 9, 10, 11, 12 from table"

Exec(@sqlStr)
```

And a string would be fairly easy to manipulate to contain relevant info..

But another question - why would you have all your data in each column instead of different rows? That way you could really easily get the data you want and show it the way you would want to..

**UPDATE:**

```
DECLARE @i int
SET @i = MONTH(getdate())

DECLARE @str nvarchar(max)
SET @str = 'SELECT '

WHILE @i <= 12
    BEGIN
        SET @str = @str + cast(@i as nvarchar(max))+ ',' 
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

SET @str = LEFT(@str, len(@str) - 1) + ' FROM TABLE'

Exec(@str)
```

Comment: More details on MS website.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198330(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Even if this works in Access, which I haven't tried yet, how is this dynamic? How do the 9, 10, 11, and 12 get dynamically selected? It looks hard coded to me, but maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Regarding the structure of the data, I inherited this DB. I am aware the structure of it could be better, but I'm not in a position to make major changes to it.

Comment: What I wrote is static sure, but a string can be easily manipulated :-) See my updated answer.

Comment: You might want to add some square brackets around the `cast(@i as nvarchar(max))` to get `SET @str = @str + '[' + cast(@i as nvarchar(max))+ '],'`

Comment: Since the other answer worked for me, and I had already started down that road, I didn't actually try this solution. Therefore, I have no idea if it works in Access. Thanks anyway for the effort.